Can Python's input be terminated with another key?
I am writing an interactive CLI and just thought about giving the user a different way of confirming an input.
So, usually I would use python's input().
With that a user would submit input by pressing Enter.
Would it be possible to let a user submit input by pressing e.g. Tab or Ctrl+D?
I wanted to make it possible to quickly use the CLI with the left hand only (Enter is far away).
I tried to work around with Ctrl+D by catching EOFError
def _input(msg: str) -> str:
    try:
        inpt = input(msg)
    except EOFError:
        pass
    return inpt

but of course that doesn't work because the exception prevents user input from being read.
sys.stdin and fileinput.input also rely on Enter.

Not with the standard text entry utilities. You might have to start using ncurses (which is in the standard library as the curses module), but that is quite a lot more work (it also can do a lot more than what you want). Or perhaps see if the readline module in the standard library can be of help.

Oh wow curses is a whole other rabbit hole

Yes, I think curses' getch is the answer

input() is not a good methods to do interfaces. It is very good for quick scripts. Simplicity and portability has a price (stdin is often is line buffered)
